# I shared a folder on Google Drive to another user with Edit rights. He can see it but, but why can't he upload a file?

Tags: google-drive

He can see the share folder. But there is no menu on the left of his drive webpage. So he can't add, create, remove anything. Just view. How come?

Answer (score 2):

To interact with *Shared with me* files, he must add it to his drive first. Then he can make copies, rename files, etc.

**Instructions**:

1. after navigating to the *Shared with me* folder, click the check-arrow next to the file.
2. At the top, in the header row, you should see a tab marked *Add to Drive*. Click that, will add file to Drive.
3. File will now be visible from *My Drive* .Changes can now be made as necessary.
4. When done, if file should be removed from Drive, from *My Drive* view, simply right-click the file and select remove.

**Note**: Ensure that you have made a copy of files to be shared. To my knowledge, the only way to remove sharing permission from people who are not in your "group" is to delete the file.